# explicity chain dependency in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

What's the pattern to follow when specialized Makefiles in a directory depends on the main one in a parent dir?

i have:

```
/
/Makefile
/src
/src/Makefile
/tests
/tests/Makefile
```

in `/Makefile` i have:

```
TESTING_COMMAND=something
dotest1:
    make -C tests/ $@
```

in `/tests/makefile` i have

```
dotest1:
    $(TESTING_COMMAND) $?
```

if i run:

```
me@host:/ $ Make dotest1
```

it works. but if i execute from the tests dir:

```
me@host:/tests/ $ Make dotest1
```

it will try to execute the test file in the shell, because $(TESTING_COMMAND) is empty, so it's first argument became the command passed to the shell.

I don't necessarily need that to work if executed in the /tests/ or /src/ dir, but need a way to gracefully fail.

Comment: Are you sure you want to define `TESTING_COMMAND` in the main makefile, even though only the tests/ makefile uses it?

Comment: I over simplified a lot on the question :) i have a lot of thing that are shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design scares me, but this will do the trick in the main Makefile:

```
TESTING_COMMAND=something
dotest1:
    make -C tests/ $@ TESTING_COMMAND=$(TESTING_COMMAND)
```

If you want `tests/Makefile` to fail well, you have a couple of options. If only that one target depends on `TESTING_COMMAND`, you can have it print a warning and do nothing:

```
ifdef TESTING_COMMAND
dotest1:
    $(TESTING_COMMAND) $?
else
dotest1:
    @echo warning: TESTING_COMMAND not defined
endif
```

Or if the whole Makefile depends on it, you can have Make print a warning or abort:

```
ifndef TESTING_COMMAND
$(warning TESTING_COMMAND is undefined, but Make will try to us it anyway)
$(error TESTING_COMMAND is undefined, Make will now abort)
endif
```

You can also have it abort the sub-make (the one that runs `tests/Makefile`) but still continue running the Make process that invoked it, but that's kind of a pain.

Comment: perfect! the ifndef looking for one var worked marvelously. The design is not that scary :) just centralize everything that can be overridden by the build actors in one core makefile, and leave the logic in the dirs that contain the code/source.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to send everything through the command line (or environment) seems like a bad idea to me.  That's what inclusion was *invented* for.  Put your common values into a separate file, something like `config.mk`, then in all your makefiles just use:

```
include config.mk
```

to get them included.